# How to get notification when phone vibrates?

Tags: android, vibration

Is it possible to get a indication when the phone vibrates? I cant seem to find any info on this....

Comment: Vibration in itself is a notification on some event occurence. So having notification for another notification does not seem logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have never tried this method. i do not know **whether it is working correctly or wrong**.

Use the getRingerMode() method in AudioManager.

AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

```
switch (am.getRingerMode()) {

    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
        displayNotification("Hi i am notification");
        break;

}
```

......

```
public void displayNotification(String msg)
{
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, msg, System.currentTimeMillis());

// The PendingIntent will launch activity if the user selects this notification
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE, new Intent(this, ExpandNotification.class), 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Title here", ".. And here's some more details..", contentIntent);

manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

and use appropriate permissions